# Migrating SP 2013 Content Database Prod->Dev with App Catalog: Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-catalog

I am trying to refresh a SharePoint 2013 Dev environment from our Prod environment. I am using a content database containing a single site collection and an app catalog site hosting 10+ SharePoint hosted add ins being used in this site collection. After restoring a copy of the content database into the Dev environment and mounting it, none of the SharePoint hosted add-ins contained within the app catalog for this site will load, and generate this error:

````
Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

default.aspx:1 Refused to display 'https://app-06fa180b8440ef.SPappsdev.net/FeatureRotator/Pages/FeatureRotatorAppPart.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdevinnergy%2Esaskenergy%2Enet&SPHostTitle=Innergy&SPAppWebUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp%2D06fa180b8440ef%2Esaskeappsdev%2Enet%2FInsiteFeatureRotator&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=3&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E5241%2E1000&FeatureWidth=725&FeatureHeight=340&MaxItems=10&Interval=10&TransitionMode=fade&SenderId=8CB6B67D3' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by migrating the App Management Service application database and Subscription Service database from Prod->Dev in addition to the content database.